# How do you find a function defined by the intersection of two other functions crossing each other at different points?

Tags: calculus, functions

Suppose you have

$f(x,J)=(x-J)$
$g(x)=-x+4$

It is easy to see that by manipulating $J$, the intersection of the two functions forms an point, and if the height of that point is considered as $h(J)$, then blind guessing on Desmos will reveal that $h(J)=-\frac{1}{2}J+2$

How would one go about finding nonlinear $h(J)$ functions like this, using just any two $f$ and $g$, through some sort of formula? Might it have to do with integrating small shifts in the intersection height?

Comment: If $x-J=-x+4$ then $2x=-J+4$ so $x=-\frac 12J +2$.  But most people would say that was a linear function of $J$.

Comment: I think I lack braincells today. Thank you.

Comment: Simply solve the equation $f(x,J)=g(x)$ for $x$. You'll get an expression $x=h(J)$, that's your function.